# Как обработать исключения и продолжить метод

Tags: c#, исключения

Как уже ранее говорилось исключать всё `catch(){}` не правильно.

```
public static void trycatch()
{
  try
  {
  // тут что-то работает ( удаление папок )
  }
  catch (DirectoryNotFoundException) { throw; } // правильно ли? 
  try
  {
    // тут что-то работает (удаление файлов)
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException) { throw; }
}
```

Как правильно обработать исключения чтобы ничего не выводилось на экран?! И продолжить работу метода?

**[Обновил]**

```
try
{
   // Удаление папок
   // Удаление файлов
}
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException) { }
catch (FileNotFoundException) { }
```

Так же нельзя) ??

```
try 
{ 
  catch() {} 
}
```

Comment: Если уберете `throw` внутри блоков `catch` - работа продолжится без бросания исключения в случае возникновения исключения. (масляное масло получилось) А вообще, можно делать один `try` с несколькими `catch`

Comment: @DenisBubnov, Но если ничего не обрабатывается это плохо?!

Comment: @ArteS, а как ты хочешь обрабатывать? :-)

Comment: @DenisBubnov, А как сразу несколько `catch`-ей организовать?

Comment: Давайте предположим, что Вы хотите удалить папку, но прав нет, но узнаете только в момент выполнения удаления и падает исключение. Вы его обрабатываете без бросания исключения, но записываете информацию по этому исключению куда-то а потом просто выводите что было не так

Comment: `try{...}catch (DirectoryNotFoundException){...}catch (FileNotFoundException){...}`

Comment: @Grundy, Обрабатывать я его не хочу, я хочу понять можно ли не обрабатывать исключения если нужно продолжить работу? Вообщем можно просто убрать `throw;` и всё нормально)

Comment: Обрабатывать исключения с пустым блоком catch можно, но не нужно, так как в случае *действительно* исключительной ситуации вы не узнаете, что произошло. Запишите хотя бы в лог информацию.

Comment: Блок Catch срабатывает только если попытка try поймала исключение. К блоку Catch прикручивается тип исключения, только для того, чтобы при поимке данного исключения срабатывали определённые инструкции. Точно по той же логике если вы ловите исключение определённого типа, блок catch, будучи пустым, clr просто посетит и пойдёт дальше по циклу. Только stackoverflowException полностью прерывает выполнение, не позволяя пройти дальше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно продолжить работу метода, но в процессе его работы могут возникнуть исключения, то блок `try{...}catch{...}` писать нужно. Просто не делайте так называемый `rethrow`, то есть внутри блока `catch` не бросайте снова исключение.

```
public static void trycatch()
{
  try
  {
     // тут что-то работает ( удаление папок )
     // тут что-то работает (удаление файлов)
  }
  catch (DirectoryNotFoundException) 
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Директория не найдена!"); // банальный пример вывода сообщения
  } 
  catch (FileNotFoundException) 
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Файл не найден!"); // вывод сообщения
  }
  catch (Exception) 
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Что-то пошло не так!"); // сообщение
  }
}
```

В данном примере есть три блока `catch`, первые два на `DirectoryNotFoundException` и `FileNotFoundException`, а третий универсальный, для всех остальных исключений `Exception`. А можно обойтись одним блоком `catch` и просто ничего не делать, к примеру:

```
public static void trycatch()
{
  try
  {
     // тут что-то работает (удаление папок, удаление файлов)
  }
  catch (Exception) // один обработчик на все исключения
  {

  } 
}
```

Выводить сообщение не обязательно, просто, если Вы считаете, что пользователь должен знать о том, что что-то нельзя сделать или что-то пошло не так - то это самый простой способ. Можно вести лог и писать в файл к примеру, но это уже на Ваш выбор и в зависимости от задачи.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение)